# onCreateView() method not found with android.support.v7.preference.Preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-appcompat

In my current app, I have changed my import for preference from "android.preference.Preference" to "android.support.v7.preference.Preference" as I am adding the support for appcompat v7 preference library.

But few overridden methods does not exist any more with support v7 preference like :
onCreateView()

Is there an alternate method for this in support preference library?

I searched over internet and tried few things, but non of them seem to work. would appreciate any work.

Thanks

Comment: Having the same problem, did you ever solve this?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

in the android.support.v7.preference.Preference you need to use override the onBindViewHolder, check out this nice example:

[creating a custom v7 preference](http://www.hidroh.com/2015/11/30/building-custom-preferences-v7/)

Answer (score -3):

This class doesn't have this method. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/Preference.html)